# Flutter: Accessing File: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an app that takes a screenshot of the entire screen when clicking a button. Apparently the image goes to: 
**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.program-name/files**

I have tested this using the android emulator as well as my physical device. The path name changes slightly, but I still have no access to this image.

I am using the following code in order to take the screenshot and save it:

```
takeScreenShot() async{
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;
    print(directory);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    File imgFile = new File('$directory/screenshot.png');
    print (imgFile.toString());
    imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
  }
```

Is there anyway to:

1. Access this file and move it elsewhere on the computer/phone or,
2. Change the following directory to one that goes to any file on your computer?

`final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;`

The idea would be to save user data on a form and save an image of the page that was just filled in for future reference. i.e. submit form, save screenshot-image to PC desktop gallery, for example.

Answer (score 3):

There are issues on this. [#48208](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48208) [#35783](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783)

On Android you can write path by yourself.

```
Future<void> _screenshot() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    Directory d = Directory('/storage/emulated/0');
    if (d.existsSync()) {
      Directory(d.path + '/MyApp').createSync();
      File imgFile = new File(d.path + '/MyApp/screenshot.png');
      print('saving to ${imgFile.path}');
      imgFile.createSync();
      imgFile.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
    }
}
```